# SML: How to recursively halve an integer n using only +1 and -1

Tags: recursion, sml

How would I split a number n recursively in SML?

```
  fun halves (n : int) : int * int =  
    let 
      val x = 0
      val y = x+1
    in 
      case n of
        x => (n, x)
      | y => (n, y)
      | _ => halves(n-1)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a homework problem?

The code you posted doesn't really make sense, because the three cases are redundant: The pattern "x" matches everything, and so does "y", and so does "_". If you want to check against 0, just write 0 in the pattern. In your code, x always has the value 0 and y always has the value 1.

Here is a hint: What if you had two functions that called each other (mutually recursive)? You can define those with fun ... and, like:

```
fun f (a, b) = g (b, a)
and g (a, b) = f (a + b, a - b)
```

(This of course just loops forever).

Answer (score 0):

You should think carefully about both your basis and your recursive step.

The basis is straightforward: `halves 0 = (0,0)`

For the recursive step -- ask yourself how you would e.g. use the fact that `halves 11 = (5,6)` to compute `halves 12`? Similarly, how would you use the fact that `halves 12 = (6,6)` to compute `halves 13`? In general, if you let `(a,b)` be `halves (n-1)`, in terms of `a` and `b` what is `halves n`?